# Extract data from huge DB table using Python and create multiple CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract data from a big Database table(Oracle) into CSV file. I am using "select * from table" query and storing results in Pandas Dataframe. Using PD.to_csv I am writing this dataframe to a CSV file. This process is taking lot of time( around 2 hrs for 4 million records, both reading data into DataFrame and writing Dataframe to CSV), so I think it will be better to create multiple CSV files with smaller data set and will work even faster if I can apply multi threading or parallel processing while extracting data from source table into CSV.

I am looking for suggestions on How to approach this performance problem?

Comment: Your details are insufficient to give any suggestions. Please give details about your code, environment, the database you are querying etc so that it will by easy for me to give suggestions.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Ritesh added more details in original post.